# How are tensors used in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensor

I'm new to learning neural networks and am trying to understand the role of tensors in them. I am trying to use some neural network libraries, but they are asking me for the dimensions. Could any one explain this concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensors seem to have a limited definition in the machine learning community, which sees them as basically multidimensional arrays (generalizing arrays and matrices).

In general in mathematics they are a structure that must satisfy some additional properties. [There are a few explanations here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198061/why-the-sudden-fascination-with-tensors).