# Is there any Good comprehensive reference for tensor calculus?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, references, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently reading this [RNN](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/) blog, where it talks about Backprop through time. I am struggling to derive it and don't understand how to go about such derivations in general. 
Stuff like this ends up being a pain point in most literature related to ML/DL/AI. Is there any resource that explains derivatives of different objects of higher dimensions in detail with proper examples.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198061/why-the-sudden-fascination-with-tensors ? Contains references.

Comment: [The Matrix Calculus You Need For Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf)