# Are the arrows connecting nodes called as Tensors?

Tags: neural-networks, tensor

I asked a close friend of mine to explain Neural Networks at high level. At one point, he explained to me the arrows that connecting nodes are called as Tensors and that each tensor has a weight.

I did research on Google only to find that Tensor is a data structure and I can't find any references pointing to what my friend told me.

So, I'd like to hear whether his statement is true or false.

Comment: The tensor stores the weights. The arrows show how the weights in one layer are related by mathematical operations to the subsequent layers. Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198061/why-the-sudden-fascination-with-tensors